# Using echo to output Javascript code from PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo, xss

I want to get familiar with Cross site scripting, so I have tried to exploit some vulnerable examples that they have provided us in class. Right now I have a form whose value is stored in `$_REQUEST['in']` of PHP when the form is submitted, and then printed somewhere else in the page when the response comes back. To print its content, another variable `$var` is used to retrieve it from `$_REQUEST['in']` and then an `echo $var` is used.

Now my bet is on writing the JS code into `$_REQUEST['in']` so that when it comes back it is printed in the HTML file and executed. The problem is that the `echo` is changing the characters `<` and `>` to their equivalent `&lt` and `&gt`, which makes the JS code to be displayed as plain text. No HTML encoding method is being used, so that is why I am kind of confused. Could you give my any hints on why this is happening?

This is the section of the file where the `$var` is being used.

```
<div id="feedback" class="alert alert-warning">
    <?php echo $var; ?>
</div>
```

I rechecked the code looking for some enconding methods but I don't see any. They include [this](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js) JS, but I don't think that the encoding is being done there since it is not directly provided to us.

Comment: They are probably being encoded to prevent against that particular cross site scripting attack. Where is the `echo $var;` being used? That might provide a clue as to how to implement an attack.

Comment: "The problem is that the echo is changing the characters `<` and `>` to their equivalent &lt and &gt" — `echo` doesn't do that. It will be a previous step which does that. Blocking XSS is a large part of the point of doing that.

Comment: Do you have the source code to the PHP page?  There's gotta be a `htmlspecialchars()` (or `htmlentities()`) call in there somewhere.  Unless they are being "converted" to `&lt;`/`&gt;` in the *request*.

Comment: I have just added more information to the post. @RocketHazmat what do you mean with conversion in the request?

Comment: @user2763158: Are you sure you aren't sending `&lt;` in the request?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, I have just used a Burp to intercept the request and by that moment the value is just the same thing that I wrote in the form.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like somewhere before the final echo is a [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) or a [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)

On a side note, echo does not make any changes to anything it just attempts to output anything you throw at it, sometimes unsuccessfully!